# flutter web http.get return "Unsupported operation: Platform._version"

Tags: flutter

I'm developing flutter web app and trying to get some data from the internet
I'm using package:http/http.dart
And trying to do this:

```
await http.get(url);
```

but I got this error:

> Unsupported operation: Platform._version

```
daz@daz:/rom/source/public/checkout_example$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.16.2-pre.41, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Could you share your `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you have figured this out by now but I just had the same problem and came across this post.

So, having now worked out the solution, I figured I would post it here to save the next person who comes across it some time.

The solution is to update the version of the `http` plugin in `pubspec.yaml`

I had been using `http: "0.11.3+17"` and getting that error.

I updated the entry in `pubspec.yaml` to `http: ^0.12.1` and it works.

Comment: I use http: ^0.12.1 and still have this issue! I am on Flutter beta channel and try to use http.get in Flutter web. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not specifically. I'm also on beta (Channel beta, 1.18.0-11.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836]) And I'm working with my web app right now actually it is still using 0.12.1 and it's working. When I have these sorts of issues I often try starting a new Flutter project, the default Counter app, stripping it back, and then putting just the single plugin and the bear minimum amount of code to try the functionality I'm stuck on. The idea being to eliminate any other factors that might be having an impact.

Comment: check other plugins in pubspec.yaml they might not be web supportive.

Answer (score 3):

The problem I had was I was explicitly using an `IOClient`, which isn't supported on the browser; a `BrowserClient` needs to be used in this case (this is using `http v0.13.3`).

The solution:

```
var client = http.Client();
```

creates the right one depending on the platform.

From the `Client()` docs:

> Creates an `IOClient` if `dart:io` is available and a `BrowserClient` if `dart:html` is available, otherwise it will throw an unsupported error.

Comment: which http version are you using?

Comment: I'm using v `0.13.3`, the most recent at the time of writing. Updating my answer

Comment: This also was the solution for me while working with web sockets, except I had to switch from `IOWebSocketChannel` to `WebSocketChannel`. (Also had to change the import from `io.dart` to `web_socket_channel.dart`.)

Comment: @sfarbota your comment saved my life :) thank you