# Unsupported operation: default SecurityContext getter when connecting with self signed certificate

Tags: flutter, https, flutter-web, dart-http

I have a flutter web app that connects to an HTTPS service that uses a self-signed certificate. I then added my certificate to my HTTP call as below:

```
    String url = "$BASE_URL/authenticate/";
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/keystore.p12');
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
    context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List(),
        password: "password");
    final httpClient = HttpClient(context: context);

    final client = IOClient(httpClient);

    final response = await client.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: jsonEncode(userObj));
```

However, I am getting the issue below:

`Unsupported operation: default SecurityContext getter`

Based on [this](https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/issues/197), the issue is that I am using mqtt_server_client instead of mqtt_server_browser. How do I tell flutter to use the latter?

I also tried bypassing the bad certificate with the code below and got a different issue related to the usage of [IOClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952087/flutter-web-http-get-return-unsupported-operation-platform-version)

```
 httpClient.badCertificateCallback =
         (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
```

error:

```
    Unsupported operation: Platform._version
```